# Laravel request/response time very slow on Docker Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-8

Does anyone have any idea why the request time of my Laravel project is running very slow? I'm running the project on Docker and I use a Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml. I'm also using nginx

I have tried multiple things like Eager loading and artisan optimize but none of those seems to work.

I'm running this on a laptop with an i7-9750H and 16gb RAM.

This what my debugbar says:

[image: This what my debugbar says]

Dockerfile in a folder named 'php':

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine

RUN apk add shadow && usermod -u 1000 www-data && groupmod -g 1000 www-data

RUN chmod 777 /dev/stdout /dev/stderr

RUN apk --update add wget \
  curl \
  git \
  grep \
  build-base \
  libmcrypt-dev \
  libxml2-dev \
  zlib-dev \
  autoconf \
  cyrus-sasl-dev \
  libgsasl-dev \
  composer \
  supervisor \
  libpng-dev \
  freetype-dev \
  libjpeg-turbo-dev \
  libjpeg-turbo-utils \
  openssh \
  htop \
  nano \
  ghostscript \
  imagemagick-dev \
  libzip-dev \
  wkhtmltopdf \
  jpegoptim \
  optipng \
  pngquant \
  pngcrush \
  gifsicle \
  bash

RUN apk add --update --no-cache graphviz font-bitstream-type1

RUN echo '* * * * * php /var/www/html/artisan schedule:run' | crontab -u www-data -
RUN rm -rf /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli pdo pdo_mysql tokenizer xml zip exif
RUN pecl channel-update pecl.php.net \
    && pecl install redis \
    && rm -rf /tmp/pear \
    && docker-php-ext-enable redis \
    && docker-php-ext-install gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv \
    && docker-php-ext-configure gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd \
    && docker-php-ext-install bcmath

# install imagick
# use github version for now until release from https://pecl.php.net/get/imagick is ready for PHP 8
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/imagick \
    && curl -fsSL https://github.com/Imagick/imagick/archive/06116aa24b76edaf6b1693198f79e6c295eda8a9.tar.gz | tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/imagick" --strip 1 \
    && docker-php-ext-install imagick

RUN rm /var/cache/apk/* && \
    mkdir -p /var/www && \
    chown www-data:www-data /var/www -R

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n", "-c",  "/etc/supervisord.conf"]

USER www-data

RUN composer global require laravel/envoy

ENV PATH "$PATH:/home/www-data/.composer/vendor/bin"
```

Dockerfile inside folder named 'nginx':

```
FROM nginx:alpine
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:

  php:
    volumes:
      - './src/:/var/www/html'
      - './.docker/php/supervisor.conf:/etc/supervisord.conf'
    tty: true
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: .docker/php/Dockerfile
    links:
      - "db:database"
      - "redis:redis"
    networks:
      internal:
      traefik:

  nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - './src:/var/www/html'
      - './.docker/nginx/nginx/conf.d/:/etc/nginx/conf.d/'
      - './.docker/nginx/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf'
    labels:
      traefik.backend: domain.test
      traefik.frontend.rule: "Host:library.test"
      traefik.docker.network: traefik
      traefik.port: 80
    networks:
      internal:
      traefik:
    depends_on:
      - php
  db:
    image: mysql/mysql-server:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'library'
      MYSQL_USER: 'amin'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'secret'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'secret'
      DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_PLUGIN: 'mysql_native_password'
    volumes:
      - mysql:/var/lib/mysql:rw
      - './database:/var/data'
    networks:
      - internal
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  # Cache server
  redis:
    image: redis:4-alpine
    volumes:
      - redis:/data:rw
    networks:
      internal:

volumes:
  mysql:
    driver: "local"
  redis:
    driver: "local"

networks:
  traefik:
    external: true
  internal:
    external: false
```

Comment: What is your host OS?  I don't see the part of the Dockerfile that `COPY`s the application into the image; is it missing?  Do you need all of those OS-level packages, or can you trim out some unnecessary ones (how does your application code use `git`, `htop`, or `nano`)?

Comment: Same, dell 5420, clear install laravel 9 on docker, 8sec response

Answer (score -2):

That's not slow.

20MB in 1.7s is about 12MB/s, with overheads that's pretty quick.

The route you're hitting is returning heaps of data, probably more than you expect, and that's why it looks like it's running slow.